# Running Dynare from Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new to Dynare++ and I have really quick question I cannot seem to find the answer too.

What is the difference between these two commands and why is the output different?

```
!dynare++ --per 50 --sim 3 file_name.mod

dynare file_name.mod
```

In the first command its unable to find steady state values based on my initial values and in the second it can. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The first command calls the standalone Dynare++ instead of Matab-based Dynare. The latter uses Matlab's solvers for numerically finding the steady state. Note that there is a dedicated forum for Dynare at https://forum.dynare.org